# jQuery animate to show and move elements

Tags: jquery

Below is an small working script I've made. Have a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/knsgp/)

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
  $("ul li a").hover(function () 
  {
    $("span", this).fadeIn('fast');
    $("label", this).fadeIn('fast');
  },
    function () 
    {
        $("span", this).fadeOut(500);
        $("label", this).fadeOut(500);
    }
  );
});
```

What I've been trying to do is changing this effect into an animation using some simple animating functions but I'm just not getting the proper result.

An example of what I'm trying to do is :

1. After hovering on `<a>` element, show the hidden `<span>` , animate its position to " left: 30px".
2. Animate the position to "bottom:100px" .

I'd appreciate any suggestion, solution or tutorial related to that  .

Comment: Provide us the HTML behind your script code. Thank you.

Comment: It's there on the first line. the " [here](http://jsfiddle.net/knsgp/) " link.

Comment: You have `$("ul li").hover` which should be  `$("ul li a").hover` as you want hover over `<a>`. Can you be clear of point 2, animate the position of?

Comment: ok. Animate the position of span and label.

Comment: Thank you friends for trying anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("ul li").on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            var self = this;
            $("span, label", this).fadeIn('fast', function() {
                $(this).stop().animate({
                    left: 30,
                    top : $(self).height() - 100
                }, 400);
            });
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            var self = this;
            $("span, label", this).stop().animate({
                    left: -30,
                    top : 0
            }, 400, function() {
                $(this).fadeOut('fast');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/knsgp/3/)

Comment: I wish I could do scripting like you my friend. I probably will :)

Comment: @John - A little practice goes a long way. Note that you can't animate the bottom position when you have'nt set the bottom position in your CSS, hence the "`parent height - 100 == 100pixels from bottom`" !

Comment: I'd try my best.Sure I set that first and then give the value to bottom. Thank you